# Calculate all the generators in $\mathbb{Z}/61$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Here's the exact question I trying answer:
"Calculate all the generators in $(\mathbb{Z}/61)^\times$ . You may assume that $g = 2$  is one such generator. "
Does this question mean calculate the number of elements that are generators, or calculate each individual generator? I can't imagine that it is asking to count the number of them because that would just be $61-1$ which is $60$, and that $g=2$ was mentioned just to confuse things. But could someone please explain how I could calculate each of the generators, using the knowledge that 2 is one them. I've looked around online, but I'm stumped. I assume there's some method for doing this other than just slow going through each element one at a time?

Comment: $4$ is not a generator of $\mathbb Z/61^*$. This should hint to you that there are not $60$ generators.

Comment: Yep. I just realized I was confusing multiplicative inverses with generators.

Comment: Hint: In a cyclic group of order 60, generated by an element $g$, the order of $g^n$ is equal to $60/\gcd(60,n)$. When is this equal to $60$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $\text{ord}(a^k) = \dfrac{\text{ord}(a)}{\gcd(\text{ord}(a), k)}$

Answer (score 2):

Hints for you to work out:

== $\;\Bbb Z/61\Bbb Z=:\Bbb F_{61}\;$ is a field .

== A *finite* subgroup of the multiplicative group of *any* field is **cyclic** .

== In a cyclic group of order $\;n\;$ there are exactly $\;\varphi(n)\;$ generators of that group (i.e., elements of order $\;n$) , with $\;\varphi=$ Euler's Totient Function

== If $\;G\;$ is a cyclic group of order $\;n\;$ and $\;G=\langle\,x\,\rangle\;$ , then **all** the generators of the group are given by

$$\;\{\,x^k\;:\;\;\text{g.c.d.}\,(k,n)=1\,\}$$

Comment: Maybe $\mathrm{gcd}(k,n) = \mathrm{gcd}(k,n-k)$ could reduce the number of calculations as well.

Comment: @GPerez Indeed so, though perhaps that is not the most important thing in this case. Thank you.

Comment: Certainly not, you've given that in your answer. Really the comment was for OP, but I put it here so it didn't look like a confusing stand-alone fact.

Comment: @Timbuc This is all true, but it seems that the question was to find all the generators *in*  $(\mathbb Z/61\mathbb Z)^\times$, thus, one needs concrete isomorphism $(\mathbb Z/61\mathbb Z)^\times \cong \mathbb Z/60\mathbb Z$. All you need to do is send a generator to a generator, and that's why the assumption that $2$ is a generator of $(\mathbb Z/61\mathbb Z)^\times$ was given. Perhaps you would like to add it to you answer, so everything is in one place. EDIT: or maybe you purposely left it out in which case I spoiled your intention. Sorry if that was the case.

Comment: @Ennar Thank you. In fact the question specifically said "you (the one to whom the question was asked) can assume $\;2\;$ is a generator", so no need to add over that, imo.